# Validate Boostrap modal contact form using Laravel 5, AJAX

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal, contact-form

Having trouble figuring out how to use a Bootstrap modal in Laravel 5 to send a contact form.

I want to use AJAX so that the page doesn't refresh.

When I click send in the modal, I get a 500 (Internal Server Error) in the console log.

What should the AJAX call look like?
what should the route look like?
What do I need in the controller to get a simple response back?

Having a difficult time finding examples of these things.

Here is my AJAX...

```
$.ajax({
  method: "post",
  url: "/results-guest-card",
  data: str,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    if (response.status == "OK") {
      console.log ('success');//Success!
      $('#guestCardModal').modal('hide');
      $('.modal-send-button').attr("disabled", false);
    } else {
      console.log ('failure');//Fail!
      $(".errors").html(result.errors);
      $('.modal-send-button').attr("disabled", false);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: 500 Internal Server is related to your Code in Laravel. In your console see the preview that larvel shows the error

Comment: Ah... I see in the preview that there is a TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53. How can I fix?

Comment: Okay.  Fixed the 500 Internal Server Error by indentifying that there was a TokenMismatchException.  Thank you Sulthan.  Found that I need to pass the token as a header in the AJAX setup. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: I have added the answer as it might helps someone to fixing the TokenMismatchException.. You shall accept if you think it deserves

Comment: Also +1 for your self fixing :) Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing answer as it might help someone in future.

As the OP said it was one because of the token.

It should be fixed by having the `csrf_token` in the forms.

**How can i have it ?**

Just have [CSRF Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection) in your form by having the csrf_token as hidden

Like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

**You can also Override it but it is seriously bad** As few really want to do it

You can remove the CSRF Token

by commenting the following in your `kernal.php` but i really won't recommend it.

```
'App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This works.  Passed the token via header in AJAX: headers:`$.ajax({ headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('input[name="_token"]').attr('value')},`

Comment: That's great :) If you need you shall update my answer too ;)